# Convertir una Array en una Lista de un objeto en C#

Tags: c#, webservice, servicio

Tengo un problema, dado a que estoy realizando un método web en donde recibo un array y quiero pasar lo de esta dentro de el a una lista de objeto, pero no he logrado hacerlo,  requiero ayuda por favor, esta es la parte del código: este es el párametro Array: (string[] BeneficiariosDetalles)
Esta parte es la del controlador

```
foreach (var item in BeneficiariosDetalles)
            {
                if (contador == 5)
                {
                    if (item.Length == 20)
                    {
                        ValidadPedidoDetalle(ref Valepago, ref guarderia,ref tarjeta, item,true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ValidadPedidoDetalle(ref Valepago, ref guarderia, ref tarjeta, item,false);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                contador++;
            }
            if (Valepago)
            {
                List<PedidoDetalleValePago> Armarbeneficiariovalepago(BeneficiariosDetalles);
            }
```

Y esta es al función

```
     private static void Armarbeneficiariovalepago(string[] Detalles)
    {
        int k = 0;
        List<string> DetallesDePedidos = new List<string>(Detalles);
        foreach (string items in DetallesDePedidos)
        {
            DetallesDePedidos.Add(Detalles[k]);
            k++;
        }
     }
```

Los dos errores que me indica son estos:

> Error    34  No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'string[]' en
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>
> Error 24  Se esperaba ; o = (no se pueden especificar argumentos de
>   constructor en la declaración)

Propiedades PedidoDetalleValePago:

```
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public TipoDocumentoIdentificacion BeneficiarioNacionaldiad { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string NumeroDocumentoIdentificacion { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BeneficiarioNombre { get; set; }
```

Por ejemplo: **string[] Detalles = new string[] {"1", "12345678", "Pedro"};**
Y deseo pasar un Array así a una List(PedidoDetalleValePago)

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo..,`string[] Detalles = new string[] {"1", "12345678", "Pedro"};`..como vas a pasar eso a un objeto de tipo `List<PedidoDetalleValePago>`? Ese `Detalles` en todo caso generaría un solo objeto de tipo `PedidoDetalleValePago`, no una lista...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien tienes un array similar al siguiente, donde cada tres campos se debe iniciar un nuevo objeto..

```
var miArray = new string[] {"1", "Identificacion", "Pedro", "2", "Identificacion", "Juan"};
var miListaDeObjetos = new List<PedidoDetalleValePago>();

for(int i = 0; i<miArray/3; i+=3){
    miListaDeObjetos.Add(new PedidoDetalleValePago {
            BeneficiarioNacionaldiad = miArray[i],
            NumeroDocumentoIdentificacion = miArray[i+1],
            BeneficiarioNombre = miArray[i+2],
    });
}
```

y en la asignación haces la conversión respectiva según el tipo de dato.

Answer (score 1):

PUedes convertir el array de string a List asi, en una sola linea

```
private static void Armarbeneficiariovalepago (string[] Detalles) {
    List<string> DetallesDePedidos = Detalles.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Gracias Ronpy me sirve, pero exactamente como puedo hacer que un String de Array sea una List de un objeto específico? es decir List<DetalleValePago>, pero al hacer esto me dice que no se puede convertir implicitamente un string a  List<DetalleValePago>.

Comment: Directamente no se puede convertir objetos asi, que propiedades tiene esa clase DetalleValePago?

Comment: Ronpy las acabo de colocar en la pregunta, esas son algunas, para que se visualicen mejor.

Comment: Agrega tambien un array con datos de ejemplo, para entender que es lo que estas recibiendo alli

Comment: Allí puse el ejemplo.

Comment: Ahora veo, estás teniendo un problema conceptual más que programatico, ese array de string lo que contiene son las distintas propiedades de un solo objeto y no de una lista. Entonces, tu controller siempre va recibir un solo objeto? o una lista de objetos? En el caso que solo reciba un objeto, puedes cambiar tu controller para que reciba directamente el tipo DetalleValePago en vez de un array de string, si recibe varios, haz que reciba un List<DetalleValePago> en vez de un array tradicional.